# Android: no response from button

Tags: java, android

First off im a newbie to android dev so im not 100% sure what im doing. I've a log-out button which works but the other button i have coded (the scan button) is no longer working, i did have it working before i put in the code for the log out button. In log cat when i press the scan button no errors at all come up which obviously suggests its not being called at all and im not sure were ive gone wrong.

```
import library.UserFunctions;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

public class menuActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private Button scan;
    private TextView contentTxt;
    UserFunctions userFunctions;
    Button btnLogout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

        scan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnbarcode);
        contentTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.manText);
        scan.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Check login status in database
        userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
        if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext()))
        {
            // user already logged in show menu
            setContentView(R.layout.menu);
            btnLogout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

            btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            { 
                public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                    login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(login);
                    // Closing menu screen
                    finish();
                }
            });

        }else{
            // user is not logged in show login screen
            Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(login);
            // Closing the menu screen
            finish();
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.btnbarcode)
        {
            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
        }   
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
    {
        //retrieve scan result
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) 
        {
            //we have a result
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();

            contentTxt.setText(scanContent);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks Folks

Comment: Does the program enter this if? `if(v.getId()==R.id.btnbarcode)`

Comment: You are either resetting your content view if the user is logged in (in the conditional `if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())){}` or starting a new activity otherwise, so your button loses it's click listener.

Comment: @zgc7009 ah right, so do i have to do everything inside the conditional then?

Comment: Long story short, in your if statement I believe you should remove setConentView(R.layout.menu); underneath //user already logged in show menu as it already is set before.

Comment: @zgc7009 That did the trick! oh my good how did i not spot that ha! Thanks! how do i mark that as the answer?

Comment: Glad I could help, trust me I (and most developers on here) have made far weirder woopsies :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove setContentView from that if condition.

Then, put your menu layout in your main layout on top and have it fill the screen. Set its visibility to be VIEW_GONE.

Instead of calling setContentView, set that menu's visibility to visible.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an easy way to handle button clicks:

lets say I have an activity, and here is an xml file for the layout that activity uses

```
<RelativeLayout ... >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="action_Clicked"
    android:text="Login" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Notice how I used `android:onClick="action_Clicked"`

this gives the button an action listener that we can then access in our class by doing the following

```
    public void action_Clicked(View view){

        switch(view.getId()){

        case R.id.btn_login:
            doStuff();
            break;
        }
    }
```

You can definitely add on click listeners in your class, but this is my preferred method.

Comment: No problem, you can handle every button under the same switch statement this way as long as you add the same onClick method name, I like it quite a lot. If this answered your question / helped you solve your problem make sure to accept it as an answer, good luck!